# RCC crashing while compiling a .qrc file

Tags: qt

Whenever I try to compile a QT Creator project with QT Quick, even the basic, automatically generated project, rcc.exe returns an error with code "Error -1073741819", according to the Creator.

This error number looks suspicious, Googling reports it's something related to File System and either too strict UAC settings (I have it disabled) or custom sound scheme (using default).

I tried to manually use rcc.exe, just to check what's happening and to my surprise, "rcc.exe stopped working..." popup appeared. I am really stumped by this.

I tried reinstalling Qt and the exact same thing is happening with the newest version, so I believe it's an OS problem.

I should add I am using Windows 10 and everything worked perfectly on this installation about 4 months ago.

EDIT: After using GDB on rcc.exe, I've got this:

```
(gdb) run

Starting program: D:\Qt\5.5\mingw492_32\bin\rcc.exe

[New Thread 4540.0x2da0]  
[New Thread 4540.0x28c0]  
[New Thread 4540.0x2c80]  
[New Thread 4540.0x2350]

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.

0x0040cc77 in ?? ()
```

Comment: Did you try setting sound scheme to "No Sounds"? Also, try this https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/3fkgpr/_/ctph10c

Comment: @Paul Thanks for the suggestion. Yeah, I tried settings "No sounds" before, it didn't help sadly. Following that subreddit solution didn't fix the issue either.

Comment: I'm only curious as i can see mingw492_32 is it 32bit version? And you have Win10 probably 64bit? Cannot be something hidden in there or in the parameters passed to the compiler?

Comment: Yup, my Windows is 64bit. I though about this a bit, maybe it's trying to use a 64-bit DLL with 32-bit, which would explain the crash. According to http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/rcc.html there are no parameters dependant on architecture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was the Windows build.

I was using build 14251, which has some problems with memory management.

After updating to 14257, everything started working flawlessly.